# Java8 list<T> to list<object[]>

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

How to parse Generic to Object[] by using stream?
I've had

```
private static <T> List<Object[]> selectData(List<T> a,
    Predicate<T> predicate) {
    ArrayList<Object[]> tmp = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for (T x : a) {
      if (predicate.test(x)) {
        tmp.add(new Object[] { x });
      }
    }   
return tmp;
}
```

but i want to do something like:

```
...//    
return a.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but i do not know how to do casting each element to Object[]

Comment: That's not casting. You must explicitly construct the array and initialize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the [`map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) function to do exactly that:

```
return a.stream()
    .filter(predicate)
    .map(o -> new Object[] { (Object) o })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[`map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) "maps" each element of the stream to its result of the given function, so that after that call all of the elements in the stream are of the type that the mapping function returned (in this case `Object[]`).

Comment: The upcast to Object is never needed.

Comment: True, but casting to Object is something that rarely happens and I like to point out if I'm doing it in my code (especially since casting to Object can very easily lead to trouble).

Comment: Every time you call `System.out.println(myCustomObject)` you are upcasting to Object, and that's but one of a myriad of examples.